# Dual of epigraph-type cones

Tags: convex-cone, dual-cone

I am trying to calculate the dual of some cones that I don't know 'a priori'.

For example, looking at MOSEK https://docs.mosek.com/MOSEKModelingCookbook-letter.pdf it seems that he already know the formula describing the dual cone and then proves that his guess is right. But and if I do not have any guess?

For example, how could I explictly calculate the dual of the following proper cone?

$$\mathbb{H}_n = \Bigg\{\,(x\oplus y\oplus \delta)\in\mathbb{R}^n_+\oplus\mathbb{R}_+^n\oplus\mathbb{R}^n\,\colon x_i\log\bigg(\frac{x_i}{y_i}\bigg)\leq\delta_i,\text{ for each } i\in [n]\Bigg\}.$$

Comment: This particular example is a product of n exponential cones (up to some minus signs), so that is answered in the cookbook you quote. In general you can often guess the right formula if you imagine the calculations to follow in the proof (one typically uses Cauchy-Schwarz for instance) and backtrack from there.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how my example is answered in the cookbook. Are you reffering to lemma 8.2? How can I use it to derive the dual?

Comment: Your cone is a product of $n$ cones (so Lemma 8.1) of the form $y\geq x\exp(-\delta/x)$, which (up to the minus sign) is the exponential cone in the cookbook's notation. If you trace through the proof of 8.2 you will see how to account for the minus.

Comment: Thanks! I could figure out some part of it.. However still struggling to do the backwards variable change.. I could find out that the dual of each term in the sum is:

Comment: Hi again! I still struggling in some parts of this problem. I found that the dual of $$\mathbb{G}_n =\Bigg\{\,(x\oplus\theta\oplus\beta) \in\mathbb{R}^n_+\oplus\mathbb{R}_+\oplus\mathbb{R}_+\,\colon \theta\sum_{i\in [n]}\exp\bigg(\frac{-x_i}{\theta}\bigg)\leq\beta \Bigg\}.$$ is $$\Bigg\{(x\oplus\theta\oplus\beta)\in\mathbb{R}_+^n\oplus\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}_+\,\colon \sum_{x_i < \beta}\bigg(x_i\log\bigg(\frac{x_i}{\beta}\bigg)-x_i\bigg)-\sum_{x_i\geq\beta}\beta\leq\theta\Bigg\}.$$. But to obtain a bijection between this cone and $\mathbb{H}_1$ I should get rid of the plus sign for $x$

Comment: But, according to my calculations, getting rid of this sign would force $x$ to be zero. Can you help me finishing this?